# How to mark that I want Ubuntu to be upgraded to the newer release so it can run in unattended mode?

Tags: 16.04

How to mark that I want Ubuntu to be upgraded to the newer release so it can run in unattended mode?

As per [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html) upgrade is done using `do-release-upgrade` tool but I simply want to mark somehow that I want system upgraded (so `unattended-upgrade` or `apt-get dist-upgrade` will do its job), not do this manually.

*Synonyms for question title so it's easier to find it in search:*
*How do I upgrade Ubuntu (Kubuntu) without using `do-release-upgrade` app?*
*How to always have latest Ubuntu (Kubuntu) release installed (similarly to Arch) without manually running `do-release-upgrade` all the time?*

Comment: It's not so simple. A release upgrade may and often need user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this guide, we will assume an upgrade is done from version 16.04 (xenial) to 17.10 (artful). This can be easily changed to your versions.

We will make default `apt-get dist-upgrade` to handle release upgrade as a result.

The following is needed to be done to automate release upgrades:

1. Add repos of release you want to install:

   ```
   TARGET_RELEASE=artful
   /usr/bin/add-apt-repository -y \
     -u 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $TARGET_RELEASE restricted multiverse universe main'
   /usr/bin/add-apt-repository -y \
     -u 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $TARGET_RELEASE-updates restricted multiverse universe main'
   /usr/bin/add-apt-repository -y \
     -u 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $TARGET_RELEASE-security restricted multiverse universe main'
   ```

   Change "artful" to the version you want to have installed. I used 
   "artful" since I needed version 17.10.
2. Create or change `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01ubuntu` file to have the following content:

   ```
   APT::Default-Release "artful";
   ```

   Change "artful" to the version you want to have installed. I used 
   "artful" since I needed version 17.10.
3. dist-upgrade will resolve dependencies but will have some packages removed it can't resolve. Usually, it's because these packages are installed from non-default release repositories. We can find repositories of these packages like this:

   ```
   CURRENT_RELEASE=xenial
   awk '/^deb .* $CURRENT_RELEASE .*/ { print $0 }' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
   ```

   (Change `xenial` to the release version you are trying to upgrade).

   Now you should change in these files "xenial" to "arful" (or the version to which you are trying to upgrade.

   Run `sudo apt-get update`.

Then dist-upgrade would handle an upgrade to a new release on its own. No need for manual `do-release-upgrade` anymore.

You can manually run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` or wait until your unattended upgrades setup will do its job automatically in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Set these options in "Software and Updates" > Updates Tab.

The "Download and Install automatically" option does unattended upgrades. Options to "Display" either immediately or weekly give you notification first.
also change the "notify me" to any newer version.
You will automatically be notified when an update will be available(given you have an active internet connection). You just need to click upgrade/continue and you will be upgraded to the newer release